# Why int* returned from function has the correct value?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm currently learning C pointers and trying to understand some behaviour. Please look at the following code snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *foo() {
  int x = 7;
  return (int *)x;
}

int main()
{
  int *p = foo();
  printf("%d", p);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:** 7

I'm wondering why 7 is printed? In my understanding 7 is stored on the stack and `(int *)x` returns the pointer to the stack memory, when `foo` returns "its piece of the stack should be cleared", so why `p*` still points to `7`. Does this happen because the memory where `7` is stored is no yet overridden by other data or something else is going on and I fully misunderstood the behaviour? Sorry if you consider my question silly, I'm just learning C

Comment: because undefined behaviour is undefined, and can include _seeming_ to work

Comment: `42` is not in your code. Why do you think 42 is stored on the stack? (it is actually possible because *undefined behavior* is invoked by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`.

Comment: returning a pointer to an object whose lifetime is limited to the function has *undefined behavior*. You should probably stop at that and not try to decipher what underlying processes lead to the value you have observed. If you do, however, really need to know, use disassembly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: `(int *)x` casts the value of `x` as a pointer to int. Of course it prints "7".

Comment: @MikeCAT I'm sorry, I made a typo in the text! It's actually 7

Comment: So what did you expect when you wrote this code?

Answer (score 5):

`(int *)x` returns not the pointer to `x` but the value of `x` converted to a pointer. Conversion from an integer to a pointer is implementation-defined. Then you printed the value of the pointer without dereferencing the pointer (with invoking *undefined behavior* by using wrong format specifier).

In typical environment where both `int` and `int*` are 4-byte long, conversion between integers and pointers are simply using the same value and therefore your code may happen to output correct result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand all those comments talking about undefined behaviour or Devolus' answer about it, this has nothing to do with any of that.

A pointer is a number, and you're returning the number 7 *as a pointer*, then using it in `main` *directly from the pointer*. There is no problem with that, you'll get the 7 you returned in your function.

No idea where you got 42 from though, it does not appear in your code.

Comment: The comments are talking about the question, not the code alone. The OP seems to want to return a pointer to a temporary. That's a problem. And he thinks that casting to int pointer is the same as returning the pointer.

Comment: So, basically in this case it happens that `7` is not an actual value(in main), but it is and address that the pointer points to? So, to get the real value I have to use something like `printf("%d", *p)` which will most likely crash since no one knows what is stored on this address. is this correct, or I misunderstood you ?

Comment: No, on the contrary, 7 is an "actual value" as you call it. And you didn't call `printf("%d", *p)`, you called `printf("%d", p)`, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Blindy Please note that `printf("%d", p)` is not fine due to using `int*` for `%d`.

Comment: Your concern is noted, it just doesn't apply to the real world where vararg parameters are always promoted to register size in which both pointers and integers fit.

Comment: Pointers are not defined in the C standard as numbers, and they are not numbers in some memory models. Many C implementations are able to use “plain numbers” as their implementation for pointers, but this does not imbue them with the same semantics as numbers: The C standard specifies limited rules that pointers must obey. It does not require them to obey the same rules as numbers, and this means compiler optimization may cause pointers to behave differently from numbers even if they are otherwise implemented with numbers. The behavior of the program is in fact not defined by the C standard.

Comment: These questions always wake you people up. Take a deep breath, it's fine, you'll never see an environment in your life where op's code will print anything other than "7".